# Read Image file from custom directory using NSBundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsfilemanager, nsbundle

Creating a custom directory which has all the images. Designing it custom because, it will help me to get the images as an when I need at various places in the configuration.

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;
filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];       
[filemgr createDirectoryAtPath: @"/Users/home/lifemoveson/test" withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes: nil error:NULL];
```

I have placed images under test folder and are of .png types.
Is there a way to retrieve the images like below.

/** UPDATED again **/

Currently this folder is under Application_Home/Resources/ImageTiles/ as per Photoscroller example. 
How can we change it to /Users/home/lifemoveson/test/ImageTiles/ folder ?

```
- (UIImage *)tileForScale:(CGFloat)scale row:(int)row col:(int)col
{
// we use "imageWithContentsOfFile:" instead of "imageNamed:" here because we don't want UIImage to cache our tiles
NSString *tileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%d_%d_%d", imageName, (int)(scale * 1000), col, row];

// Currently this folder is under <Application_Home>/Resources/ImageTiles/ as per Photoscroller example. 
// How can we change it to /Users/home/lifemoveson/test/ImageTiles/ folder ?
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:tileName ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
return image;
}
```

Comment: Did u get any solution? am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applications running on iOS are sandboxed; you can't simply create directories wherever you please.  Your `createDirectoryAtPath:` call will fail.  You should use [one of the directories set aside for your application](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW12) instead.

Once you obtain the path for one of those directories, getting the path for files within them is simply a case of using `NSString`'s `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` method.

Comment: Hi Jim. I really thought so initially that ios would not be able to read files from the directories where I like. I have updated my question. Now how can I use NSString`s stringByAppendingPathComponent to get the image?

Comment: I am looking to insert images in various folders according to their names like : <Application_home>/lifemoveson/test or <Application_home>/lifemoveson/test1 or <Application_home>/lifemoveson/test2. so that in future I know which folder to look into without having to worry about the path name.

Comment: Yes, but which part are you stuck on?  Have you tried to use the solution I gave?

Comment: I have again edited the question. I am not sure how to get the files by simply using NSString`s stringByAppendingPathComponent: ?

Comment: Well what do you have?  You have an `NSString` with the path of the directory, you have the name of the PNG file, and you have a method that adds them together.  You have everything you need.  All you have to do is call that method on the directory path with the name of the PNG file, and it will give you the path to the PNG file.

Answer (score 0):

Makin a call to the functions such as

```
NSString* newDirPath = [self createDirectoryWithName:@"Test"];
if (newDirPath) {
    [self saveFile:@"MasterDB.sqlite" atPath:newDirPath];
}
```

which are implemented as follows

```
-(NSString*)createDirectoryWithName:(NSString*)dirName{

    NSArray* directoryArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask , YES);
    NSString* directoryPath = [directoryArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* newPath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",dirName]];
    NSFileManager *filemamager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];       
    BOOL flag = [filemamager createDirectoryAtPath:newPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes: nil error:NULL];
    return flag == YES ?newPath: nil;
}

-(BOOL)saveFile:(NSString*)fileName atPath:(NSString*)path{

    BOOL success;

    // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
    // of the File and to copy it over if required
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Check if the File has already been created in the users filesystem
    NSString *filePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath];

    // If the File already exists then return without doing anything
    if(success) return YES;

    // If not then proceed to copy the File from the application to the users filesystem

    // Get the path to the database in the application package
    NSString *pathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem

    NSError *error = nil;

    BOOL flag = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:pathFromApp toPath:filePath error:&error];

    return flag;
}
```

might help you solve your problem. Creating a directory is achieved using first function and the second will let you save files from your application bundle to any of the previously created directory. I hope you can modify it save files located at places other than Application bundle to suit to your need.

Comment: Thank you Rahul. But I guess I have not been precise yet. I have changed my question again. Let me know if the above scenario is possible ?

Comment: I am not able to figure out as to where do you want to create the directory ? You can create custom directories in the document folder of your application running on device. The path @"/Users/home/lifemoveson/test" is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: thanks..i guess since iphone device is like a sandbox, it can create document folders within the application folder only. and hence my query is ambiguous wrt iphone.